# Can one prove or apply theorems in abstract algebra, without understanding their set-interpretation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Can one prove or apply theorems in abstract algebra, without understanding their set-interpretation, using only "symbol shuffling" using the axioms of groups, rings, and so forth, as symbolic rules?

Comment: The axioms of group theory form what's called a first order theory in mathematical logic. If we assume certain rules of deduction and logical axioms then yes, all theorems in group theory may be proved formally from the group theoretic axioms simply by manipulating the $1$rst order sentences (e.g. "$ \forall x \exists y (xy=yx=e)"$). This is true of any axiomatic system in mathematics that is defined using logical symbols.

Comment: And are there also statements that can be proven in the standard "non-symbolic" way, but that are not provable using only symbolic logic? The reason I'm considering it, is that Godel's first incompleteness  theorem states that there are statements that cannot be proven nor disproven from a set of axioms, using a sequent calculus, but it doesn't say anything about them being provable or disprovable via some other non-sequent calculus method.

Comment: I'm not sure that there exist non-formal proofs that couldn't be translated into formal proofs, if that's what you mean. Gödel's incompleteness theorems simply tell us that for any first order theory powerful enough to express certain truths about the natural numbers $\omega$ is incapable of proving at least one true statement $\sigma$ about $\omega$. That is not to say there is no formal system in which $\sigma$ has a proof (hint: try the first order theory $T=\{ \sigma \}$).